# How can I setup font aliasing in operating system level

Tags: fedora, fonts

I am using Fedora 26 and Libre Office, and when writing an MLA paper, I prefer saving the file to .docx format and use "Times New Roman" to let file sharing easy. However, I cannot install the font "Times New Roman" on my computer, and my satisfied alternation is "Nimbus Roman No9 L".

Is it possible to let the operating system treat "Times New Roman" as "Nimbus Roman No9 L"? Copying and editing files with root privileges is okay for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a copy of the font, rename it in FontForge to Times New Roman and use it that way, or you can install the msttcorefonts package to obtain the original font from here http://mscorefonts2.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Note, there is a cli utility `ttx` in the fedora `fonttools` package that will convert a ttf font to "ttx" which is an editable xml format so you easily use sed to change the name (which occurs several times), then convert it back to ttf. Place the file in your `~/.local/share/fonts/` directory.

Comment: The `ttx` command helps me change the font name easily.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you. You can setup a personal font configuration as described [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/fontconfig-user.html) in your home directory under the name `~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf`. It is an XML file. Using some examples I put the following in the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
 <match>
   <test name="family"><string>Times New Roman</string></test>
   <edit name="family" mode="assign" binding="strong">
     <string>Nimbus Roman No9 L</string>
   </edit>
 </match>
</fontconfig>
```

Before this, when looking for `Times New Roman`, I had the following result:

```
$ fc-match 'Times New Roman'
LiberationSerif-Regular.ttf: "Liberation Serif" "Regular"
```

and after adding the configuration file I had

```
$ fc-match 'Times New Roman'
n021003l.pfb: "Nimbus Roman No9 L" "Regular"
```

Comment: This solution seems to match the font in fc-match correctly, but I cannot select "Times New Roman" in a graphical application (like Gedit and LibreOffice). i.e. I cannot set my Gedit font "Times New Roman" or write a document with this font. Is there other steps required to register the font?